# Django ORM filter model where all relation have value equals to

Tags: django, orm

Lets say that I have two models:

```
class Worker(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    
    
class Task(models.Model):
    worker = models.ForeignKey(Worker)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

I would like to retrieve all workers where ALL tasks are called "dig". But I dont want workers that have only one Task called "dig".

I've tried using filter and exclude with Q, like this:

```
Worker.objects.filter(task__name='dig').exclude(~Q(task__name='dig'))
```

But it didn't work, it don't remove those that have only one task like that.

I could iterate over worker and tasks to find it, but is there any way to make this query using only orm?

Comment: `Worker.objects.filter(task__name__in=['dig'])` does this solve the problem?

Comment: No, it stills retrive those Workers who have only one task with this name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Annotate your queryset with the count of matching tasks and a total count, then filter where the total is greater than one and the number matching is equal to the total

```
from django.db.models import Count, F, Q
Worker.objects.annotate(
    num_tasks=Count('task'),
    num_digs=Count('task', filter=Q(task__name='dig'))
).filter(
    num_tasks__gt=1,
    num_tasks=F('num_digs')
)
```

Comment: Is it necessary to filter num_tasks__gt=1?

Comment: @Hubertokf this filter removes Workers that only have one related Task named "dig"